# kpartx doesn't create block device

Tags: loop-device, device-mapper

I am trying to create some block devices with losetup and kpartx as follow:

```
#losetup --show -f disk.img
/dev/loop0
#kpartx -avs /dev/loop0
#
```

so nothing happend, and kpartx -l gives nothing as well:

```
#kpartx -l /dev/loop0
#
```

the mapper directory is empty:

```
#ll /dev/mapper/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root      60 Apr 14 18:43 ./
drwxr-xr-x 20 root root    4340 Apr 14 18:43 ../
crw-------  1 root root 10, 236 Apr 14 18:43 control
#
```

I am running ubuntu 16.04.2

```
#uname -a
Linux ganeti 4.4.0-72-generic #93-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 31 14:07:41 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
#dpkg -l | grep kpartx
ii  kpartx                             0.5.0+git1.656f8865-5ubuntu2.4             amd64        create device mappings for partitions
#lsmod | grep ^dm*
drbd                  348160  0
drm_kms_helper        155648  1 ast
dca                    16384  3 igb,ixgbe,ioatdma
drm                   364544  4 ast,ttm,drm_kms_helper
```

I don't see dm_mod module, so I tried:

```
#modprobe dm_mod
#
```

so I tried the following steps:

1. purged kpartx and reinstalled it
2. reinstalled the kernel

problem still there!

Any idea? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you sure there is a partition table on `/dev/loop0` which is `disk.img`? Can you run `fdisk` on it (of `gdisk` or something else if it's GPT) to show?

Comment: Thanks a lot @Celada , there wasn't a partition table on `/dev/loop0/`. Now I can go on. Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi, i'm having the same problem even though there is an image on the loop device, kpartx does not create a mapper for that loop device.
how was the problem resolved ?

Comment: @Mheni you might have got this to work, any way you need to create a partition table on `/dev/loop0/`